# How to show or hide some content on a node view using Page Manager based on the url destination?

Tags: 7, redirection

After certain fields have been set on the edit node form and saved, I don't want the node author to change these anymore and therefore I have created a new variant with a response code **"301 permanent redirect**" in Page Manager.

My redirect destination is set to `%node:url?destination=no-edit-permission`
And it does redirect the author to the intended node view (node_view in Page Manager).
But the reason I set this url destination is to be able to inform the user by showing a message at the top of that redirected page that says **"You cannot edit this page any longer**".
So how do I set such a message based on the destination in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a **visibility rule** that you can set on a particular content using the String: URL path.

### Step 1:

take only the destination parameter: e.g. `*?destination=no-edit-permission` where the (*) asterisk is the wild card and represents whatever comes in front of that string.

### Step 2:

In the **Configure visibility rule for New custom content**

set the option to:

> Allow access on the following pages

and tick the box:

> Reverse (NOT)

That should hide that content block based on the destination parameter. Yay!

[image: a snapshot of the visibility rule]
[image: a snapshot of the String: URL Path settings]

Comment: Oops! This doesn't work.